# Error in fetching data from database table

Tags: java, android, sql, eclipse, sqlite

I am making an android app. and am trying to fetching data from column, name and score from

the database table but getting this error at run time,

Sorry this application has stopped unexpectedly.

This is my Code from Database Class,

```
public long addscore(String name, int score)
{

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_name, name); 
    values.put(KEY_score, score);

    // Inserting Row
    return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, values);
}
public Cursor getScore(long rowId) throws SQLException 
{
    Cursor mCursor = db.query(true,DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {
            KEY_scoreid,KEY_name,KEY_score },,KEY_scoreid + "="
            + rowid,null,null,null,null,null);
    if (mCursor != null) 
    {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;

}
```

And this is the code of class from where i m trying to

fetch the Data from Database table (Highscore.java),

```
public class Highscore extends Activity
{
TextView name1,name2,name3,name4,name5,score1,score2,score3,score4,score5;
DBAdapter db1;
Cursor c;
int id;
String n1,n2,n3,n4,n5;
String s1,s2,s3,s4,s5;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.highscore);
    Button backbtn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.backbtn);

    OnClickListener listener=new OnClickListener() 
    {
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            Intent i=new Intent(Highscore.this,MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
    };
    backbtn.setOnClickListener(listener);
    id=1;
    name1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.name1);
    score1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.score1);



    db1=new DBAdapter(this);
    db1.open();

    c=db1.getScore(1);

        n1=c.getString(1);
        name1.setText(n1);
        s1=c.getString(2);
        score1.setText(s1);

        c=db1.getScore(2);
        n2=c.getString(1);
        name2.setText(n2);
        s2=c.getString(2);
        score2.setText(s2);

    c=db1.getScore(3);
        n3=c.getString(1);
        name3.setText(n3);
        s3=c.getString(2);
        score3.setText(s3);
        id++;   
    c=db1.getScore(4);
        n4=c.getString(1);
        name4.setText(n4);
        s4=c.getString(2);
        score4.setText(s4);
        id++;
    c=db1.getScore(5);
        n5=c.getString(1);
        name5.setText(n5);
        s5=c.getString(2);
        score5.setText(s5);

    c.deactivate();
    c.close();
    db1.close();
    }
```

}

This time i am only fetching 5 names and scores.

Here's my Logcat Error,

```
09-19 12:01:36.046: D/AndroidRuntime(455): Shutting down VM
09-19 12:01:36.046: W/dalvikvm(455): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
09-19 12:01:36.066: E/AndroidRuntime(455): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-19 12:01:36.066: E/AndroidRuntime(455): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.quizapp/com.example.quizapp.Highscore}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-19 12:01:36.066: E/AndroidRuntime(455):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
09-19 12:01:36.066: E/AndroidRuntime(455):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
09-19 12:01:36.066: E/AndroidRuntime(455):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
09-19 12:01:36.066: E/AndroidRuntime(455):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
09-19 12:01:36.066: E/AndroidRuntime(455):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-19 12:01:36.066: E/AndroidRuntime(455):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-19 12:01:36.066: E/AndroidRuntime(455):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
09-19 12:01:36.066: E/AndroidRuntime(455):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-19 12:01:36.066: E/AndroidRuntime(455):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
09-19 12:01:36.066: E/AndroidRuntime(455):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
09-19 12:01:36.066: E/AndroidRuntime(455):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
09-19 12:01:36.066: E/AndroidRuntime(455):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-19 12:01:36.066: E/AndroidRuntime(455): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-19 12:01:36.066: E/AndroidRuntime(455):  at com.example.quizapp.Highscore.onCreate(Highscore.java:59)
09-19 12:01:36.066: E/AndroidRuntime(455):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
09-19 12:01:36.066: E/AndroidRuntime(455):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
09-19 12:01:36.066: E/AndroidRuntime(455):  ... 11 more
```

If you people are not getting any thing from my question so please ask..
Please help me to Solve out the Error.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: From logs it's clear that you're getting `java.lang.NullPointerException` so you need to debug to know the cause of it or you should specify at which line you are getting exception.

Comment: what is line no 455??

Comment: Where's your `onCreate()` method?

Comment: When i am fetching only first row then the app is working fine and its showing the data of first row but when i write code to fetch data of second row then it gives an Force Close error. @Pradeep Simha

Comment: Please post `Highscore.java`. That will help us trace the `NullPointerException`.

Comment: @Deepak bala Updated. Now you can see.

Answer (score 0):

From what I see you problem is not in the database connection, you have some untreated exceptions. You have a NULL pointer exception also in onCreate(Highscore.java:59)

You can do a thing: comment parts of the code until you get a working app(that does nothing) and then uncomment until you find the exact code that crashes the app, it is easy to do and usually you will find the line that is problematic

Good luck

Comment: lordache When i am fetching only first row then the app is working fine and its showing the data of first row but when i write code to fetch data of second row then it gives an Force Close error.

Comment: Does it crash on the fetch?  c=db1.getScore(2); or anoother line?

Comment: lordache Yeah it crashes on the same line

Comment: Do this name1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.name1);
    score1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.score1); for name2 and score2

Comment: lordache This was really a silly mistake.I m felling guilty to ask this type of silly questions here by the way thanks for telling this.Now i am Happy

Answer (score 0):

Use this code insted of your.....

```
public Cursor getScore(long rowId) throws SQLException 

{

 Cursor mCursor = db.query(true,DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {
            KEY_scoreid,KEY_name,KEY_score },KEY_scoreid + " ='"
            + rowid + "'",null,null,null,null,null);

  if (mCursor != null) 
    {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;

}
```